# Take the value of the attribute, in the map, but with names of different attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new here on the site, I have a question regarding a function in react that I am unable to resolve. The solution is very simple but it does not work for me.

I build a social network in React, in the social network I have users, each user has a different name, it's like a key.

I have a match object, which contains matches between one user, represented by handle, and the other users represented by match_(number).

Because each of the users' names is unique, I want to use them in the key.
The problem is that for each user the name of the atribute is different, and I can not think of a way, to be able to access in a loop for all users.

```
match = 
[
  {handle: "backend4" , ...},
  {match_1: "backend1" , ...},
  {match_2: "backend2" , ...},
  {match_3: "backend3" , ...},
  {match_4: "devops1" , ...},
  {match_5: "devops2" , ...},
  {match_6: "mobile2" , ...},
  {match_7: "test500" , ...},
  {match_8: "testing100" , ...},
  {match_9: "testing200" , ...},
  {match_10: "testtttttt" , ...},
];


recentMatchesMarkup = match.map((singleMatch) =>
 <Match key={singleMatch.id} matchInfo={singleMatch} />)
        );
```

I'm sure the problem is very small, but I can 't think of how to deal with it

Comment: The `match_X` properties should be an array of handles

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do `<Match key="match_X" matchInfo={foo} />`, where `match_X` is `match_1`, `match_2`, ... and `foo` is `match.match_X`?

Comment: you cannot map on an object, if you are trying to get all keys use Object.keys()

Comment: @AnsonH Thank you very much, I'm sorry I corrected the question, by the way the handle inside the object I do not need, it is only for convenience, that I will know to whom the match belongs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could access the value of `match_x`, x being the index of the loop :

`match.map((el, i) => console.log(el[`match_${i}`]))`

(There is the special quote wrapping `match_${i}` above. I just can't display it since they are used to display code.. see [this link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) if you don't know about it).

But note that is only works with a key `match_x` so if you are 100% sure it's ok for you, go for it.
The first key `handle` won't be displayed (return undefined) so you might need to add a condition to display your `<Match>` component.

To be sure each match correspond to the index, here is [an example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-nqttai) about how you could do it, and here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [sortedMatch, setSortedMatch] = React.useState([]);
  const match = [
    { handle: "backend4" },
    { match_2: "backend2" },
    { match_3: "backend3" },
    { match_1: "backend1", test: "text" },
    { match_4: "devops1" },
    { match_5: "devops2" },
    { match_6: "mobile2" },
    { match_7: "test500" },
    { match_8: "testing100" },
    { match_9: "testing200" },
    { match_10: "testtttttt" }
  ];
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const matchByIndex = [];

    match.forEach(el => {
      const key = Object.keys(el).find(k => k.includes("match"));
      if (key) {
        let nb = key.split("_");
        nb = nb[nb.length - 1];
        matchByIndex[nb] = el;
      }
    });
    setSortedMatch(matchByIndex);
  }, []);

  if (!sortedMatch.length) return <>Loading...</>;
  return (
    <div>
      {sortedMatch.map((el, i) => (
        <>
          {el[`match_${i}`]}
          <br />
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I think there could be a problem, because the match_x are not sorted by order within the array, how can I be sure they are sorted by order?

Comment: @Haham I edited my answer to give you a example of how you can filter your data. But if you can rework you api to get something cleaner it would be much better. This code is very specific so be careful.